# Azure PHP SAS for blob

Tags: php, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create a `SAS` for my azure blob storage, but i'm getting the message that my signature fields are not well formed.

First a function that creates the signature:

```
function getSASForBlob($accountName,$container, $blob, $resourceType, $permissions, $expiry,$key){

    /* Create the signature */
    $_arraysign = array();
    $_arraysign[] = $permissions;
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = $expiry;
    $_arraysign[] = '/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = "2014-02-14"; //the API version is now required
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';
    $_arraysign[] = '';

    $_str2sign = implode("\n", $_arraysign);    

    return base64_encode(
    hash_hmac('sha256', urldecode(utf8_encode($_str2sign)), base64_decode($key), true)
    );
}
```

Then a function that provides me the URL:

```
function getBlobUrl($accountName,$container,$blob,$resourceType,$permissions,$expiry,$_signature){
    /* Create the signed query part */
    $_parts = array();
    $_parts[] = (!empty($expiry))?'se=' . urlencode($expiry):'';
    $_parts[] = 'sr=' . $resourceType;
    $_parts[] = (!empty($permissions))?'sp=' . $permissions:'';
    $_parts[] = 'sig=' . urlencode($_signature);
    $_parts[] = 'sv=2014-02-14';

    /* Create the signed blob URL */
    $_url = 'https://'
    .$accountName.'.blob.core.windows.net/'
    . $container . '/'
    . $blob . '?'
    . implode('&', $_parts);

    return $_url;
}
```

Then I call the functions and specify the parameters.

```
$container = '87d57f73-a327-4344-91a4-27848d319a66';
$blob = '8C6CBCEB-F962-4939-AD9B-818C124AD3D9.mp4';
$endDate = date('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD', strtotime('+1 day'));

$_signature = getSASForBlob($accountName,$container,$blob,'b','r',$endDate,$accountKey);
$_blobUrl = getBlobUrl($accountName,$container,$blob,'b','r',$endDate,$_signature);
```

https://ttresources.blob.core.windows.net/87d57f73-a327-4344-91a4-27848d319a66/8C6CBCEB-F962-4939-AD9B-818C124AD3D9.mp4?se=2016201620162016-FebFeb-ThuThuCET1111%3A0202CET3600Thu&sr=b&sp=r&sig=1VdOjLX179wLQv5o265JBR%2B6CaLTr1nwCs6GHSVqfbA%3D&sv=2014-02-14

This is the url I get as my result, when I follow it I'm getting the next error message:

> `AuthenticationFailed` Server failed to
>   authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header
>   is formed correctly including the signature.
>       RequestId:41f089a3-0001-0027-376f-6966d1000000
>       Time:2016-02-17T10:38:00.2724783Z Signature fields not well
>   formed.

Answer (score 1):

As the issue is that you have made the wrong datetime format. According the [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140255.aspx):

> The signedstart and signedexpiry fields must be expressed as UTC times and must adhere to a valid ISO 8601 format. Supported ISO 8601 formats include the following:
>
> - YYYY-MM-DD
> - YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD
> - YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD

And in PHP, you should create the datetime in the following format:

```
$expiry = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', strtotime('+1 day'));
```

Then it will be the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in the way you're constructing `canonicalizedresource`. Please remove `/` before `$accountName` from this line:

```
$_arraysign[] = '/' . $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
```

So it should be:

```
$_arraysign[] = $accountName . '/' . $container . '/' . $blob;
```

Based on the documentation [`here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140255.aspx):

```
URL = https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/music/intro.mp3 
canonicalizedresource = "myaccount/music/intro.mp3"
```

Comment: Still getting the same result with this modification

Comment: Another thing I noticed is the `se` parameter in your URL (`2016201620162016-FebFeb-ThuThuCET1111%3A0202CET3600Thu`). Can you please check if you're passing proper value for SAS Expiry?